# How can I add more values to a Picklist in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I have to show many values in a Picklist, and up to certain limit it works. However, it throws an error when it reaches a certain limit when I assign to it. So help me out, how can I manage to store more values in a Picklist?

Formula is like below:

```
CASE( Name, 
"Virgin Australia",HYPERLINK("http://www.virginaustralia.com/Personal/Bookings/Managebookings/index.htm","Virgin Australia"),
"Virgin Atlantic",HYPERLINK("https://www.virgin-atlantic.com/en/us/manageyourflights/updatebooking/index.jsp","Virgin Atlantic"),
"Virgin America",HYPERLINK("http://www.virginamerica.com/view-itinerary.html","Virgin Australia"),
"US AIR",HYPERLINK("http://reservations.usairways.com/Default.aspx","Virgin America"),
"United Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.united.com/page/genericpage/0,,52172,00.html?navSource=dropDown&linkTitle=itineraries","United Airlines"),
"Turkish Air",HYPERLINK("http://www4.thy.com/mybookings/reservations.tk?target=view&lang=en","Turkish Air"),
"Turkish Air",HYPERLINK("http://www.thaiair.com/AWR_PREM/view-trip.jsp","Turkish Air"),
"Swiss Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.swiss.com/web/EN/Pages/index.aspx?Country=US","Swiss Airlines"),
"Southwest Airlines",HYPERLINK("https://www.southwest.com/flight/lookup-air-reservation.html?int=GSUBNAV-AIR-RETRIEVE&forceNe...","Southwest Airlines"),
"South African",HYPERLINK("https://www.flysaa.com/Journeys/reservation/searchpnr.action?nameSpace=reservation","South African"),
"Singapore Airlines",HYPERLINK("https://www.singaporeair.com/manageBooking-flow.form?execution=e1s1","Singapore Airlines"),
"QATAR AIRWAYS",HYPERLINK("http://www.qatarairways.com/us/en/homepage.page","QATAR AIRWAYS"),
"Qantas Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/your-booking/global/en","Qantas Airlines"),
"Malaysia",HYPERLINK("https://book.malaysiaairlines.com/itd/itd/lang/en/reservations","Malaysia"),
"Lufthansa",HYPERLINK("http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/us/my_account/my_bookings","Lufthansa"),
"KLM - Royal Dutch Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/index.htm#tab=db_mmb","KLM - Royal Dutch Airlines"),
"Japan Air",HYPERLINK("http://www.5971.jal.co.jp/eng/SearchReservation.do","Japan Air"),
"Etihad Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.etihadairways.com/sites/etihad/_layouts/etihad/obe/RetrieveBooking.aspx","Etihad Airlines"),
"Emirates",HYPERLINK("https://fly.emirates.com/MYB/MMBLogin.aspx","Emirates"),
"Delta Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.delta.com/","Delta Airlines"),
"Copa Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.copaair.com/sites/US/EN/Pages/homepage.aspx","Copa Airlines"),
"Continental Airlines",HYPERLINK("http://www.continental.com/web/en-US/apps/reservation/default.aspx","Continental Airlines"),
"")
```

Gets Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (5,171 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could address this in a couple of ways.

My preferred way is to use workflow field updates. You could split up your case statements into individual workflows and update a field with with the right link. That way you are splitting the formula calculations into a couple of workflows.

Example:

```
Workflow A:
If "Virgin Atlantic" OR "Virgin Atlantic" OR...
THEN Update the field

Workflow B:
If "Swiss Airlines" OR "Southwest Airlines" OR...
THEN Update the field
```

And so on....

Comment: its too lenghty b,cuse iy have abotu 50 + items then i have to create a 50 workflow thats too hectic.let me know your thought

Answer (score 1):

At this size you're entering the code-zone. This is when it's time for Apex and Visualforce, even though you may not want to deal with the code management. Not knowing what your destination environment is it's hard to say what the optimal solution would be. For example, if you were writing an application to sell to others or if you're just configuring your own company's Salesforce org to suit your needs - it changes the approach.

If you don't want to manage an entire Visualforce page to handle all of your detail fields and related lists, consider doing a slim, inline VF page with only the field(s) you need (like the massive picklist mentioned above).

For example:

Apex

```
public List<SelectOption> customList
{
   get
   {
      List<SelectOption> retVal = new List<SelectOption>();

      retVal.add(new SelectOption('value1', 'Label 1'));
      retVal.add(new SelectOption('value2', 'Label 2'));
      retVal.add(new SelectOption('value3', 'Label 3'));
      // ...            

      return retVal;
   }
   private set;
}
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!controller.theSelection}">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!customList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 on visual force. An alternative might be to split up the options for the user using  field dependencies. But it doesn't sound like it would apply to you in this instance because you're hitting the code wall- not an 'option' wall.

You can set up a field dependency like this. Controlling Field = A-Z and the dependents are the associated airlines with that letter